# Read last messages using Telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm trying to retrieve last messages (and also latest messages) from a specific channel I'm subscribed to.

I tried the following code:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync

# Remember to use your own values from my.telegram.org!
api_id = 'xxx'
api_hash = 'xxx'
client = TelegramClient('xxx', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats='Channel 123'))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    print(event.raw_text)

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

For some reason, it's not working as it says "Channel 123" not detected.

What's the proper way to get messages from a specific channel (that I don't own but am subbed to)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the channel_id in this line

`@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats='channel_id'))`

Sometimes, you can use the alias of the channel, but for private channels you can see the `channel id` opening telegram in the web browser and selected the chat, in the search box where appear the url, in the final of this appear the id like this example:

```
https://web.telegram.org/k/#-1515693207
```

This is the id `-1515693207`

Another method is to use get_entity function to obtain the id, and pass it to the function you want to get the messages.

```
channel_entity = await client.get_entity(PeerChannel(client.message.to_id.channel_id))
```

Hope this help you.